# Drawing signals with foreach

Tags: foreach, tikz-timing

[image]

How to draw this signal especially sawtooth using foreach. Square wave is clock signal can be drawn using `tikztimingtable` package. Is there any other better way to draw these signals in `circuitikz`? Commands for clock signal

```
\begin{tikztimingtable}[
    timing/slope=0,         % no slope
    timing/coldist=2pt,     % column distance
    xscale=4,yscale=4, % scale diagrams
    semithick               % set line width
  ]
 % \scriptsize
M$_N$   &  10{2C} G \\
 \extracode
 \makeatletter
\end{tikztimingtable}%
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

From the `tikz-timing` manual it doesn't look like the package supports non-square waves.

Below is an example of how to draw such a thing in plain `tikz` using `\foreach` as you ask. The same would probably work in `circuitikz` as well.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.5]
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (7,2);
  \draw[thick] (0,1) node[anchor=base east] {$\mathsf{M}_N$} -- ++(1,0)
    \foreach \x in {1,...,3}{
    -- +(0,.5) -- +(1,.5) -- +(1,0) -- ++(2,0)
    } -- +(0,.5);
  \draw[thick] (0,0) node[anchor=base east] {$S$} -- ++(1,0)
    \foreach \x in {1,...,3}{
    -- +(1,.5) -- +(1.2,0) -- ++(2,0)
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: waves]

Hopefully it's not too hard to see how to extend this to other wave shapes and larger tables.